# jQuery set background: -webkit-linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### Work In Progress...

```js
var value = 0,
  pos = 0,
  progressHidden = false,
  progressEl = $('.ProgressPercent'),
  timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

var ProgressColourTween = [
  "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
  "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
  "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
  "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
  "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
  "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
  "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
  "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
  "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
  "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
];

function progress() {

  // run counter
  value++;
  if (value <= 100) {
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').text(value);
    $('.Overlay .Percent').text(value);
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressPercent .Sign').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent').css({
      background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%)"
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.ProgressWrap {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Sign {
  float: left;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Sign {
  float: left;
}
.ProgressWrap > span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProgressWrap">
  <div class="Overlay">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ProgressPercent">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Problems & Questions

**1). Overlaid Text Does Not Appear To Be Same Size**

You can still see the blending colours where the overlaid text is. This is noticeable on the percentage sign above.

**2). Manipulating `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);` Using jQuery**

As you can see from the above, I am trying to set `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);` via jQuery so I can then make it so that I can manipulate the percentages which will be `100 - value`

### Without jQuery Background Attempt:

```js
var value = 0,
  pos = 0,
  progressHidden = false,
  progressEl = $('.ProgressPercent'),
  timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

var ProgressColourTween = [
  "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
  "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
  "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
  "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
  "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
  "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
  "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
  "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
  "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
  "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
];

function progress() {

  // run counter
  value++;
  if (value <= 100) {
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').text(value);
    $('.Overlay .Percent').text(value);
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressPercent .Sign').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.ProgressWrap {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Sign {
  float: left;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Sign {
  float: left;
}
.ProgressWrap > span {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProgressWrap">
  <div class="Overlay">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ProgressPercent">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what Question is? What issue are you having?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you don't understand @guest271314? I am asking how to set the specific CSS via jQuery and why the overlaid text does not cover the other text 100% when they are both the same font and size

Comment: What is expected result? What issue are you having achieving expected result?

Comment: Are you referring to the outline color at `%` character?

Comment: @guest271314 Remove the `$('.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent').css({` and you see the same `#CCCCCC` colour as you see on the "%" on the numbers however I need to set this via my script. Also the text overlay does not cover the other text despite being the same font and size.

Comment: Still not certain what you are referring to? Other than an minimally perceptible contrasting outline at top of characters. Why do you use `float` and only set `.ProgressWrap .Overlay` `position` to `absolute`?

Comment: Just tested, regardless you can still see colour around the `#CCC` font, if you can submit an answer showing otherwise this would be helpful along with any idea how to set `$('.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent').css({ background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%)" });` with it working to display correctly this would be very helpful

Comment: Is requirement to not display a perceptible contrast at top of characters?

Comment: Yes, I need this percentile displayed overlay as I will be manipulating via using `100 - value` to display more and more of the colour

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) to adjust contrasts between content and background.

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property describes how an element's content
>   should blend with the content of the element's direct parent and the
>   element's background.

For example, using `overlay` value set at `.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent, .ProgressWrap .Overlay .Sign` selectors

```js
var value = 0,
  pos = 0,
  progressHidden = false,
  progressEl = $('.ProgressPercent'),
  timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

var ProgressColourTween = [
  "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
  "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
  "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
  "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
  "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
  "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
  "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
  "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
  "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
  "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
];

function progress() {

  // run counter
  value++;
  if (value <= 100) {
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').text(value);
    $('.Overlay .Percent').text(value);
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressPercent .Sign').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent').css({
      background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%)"
    });
  }
  
}
```

```css
.ProgressWrap {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Sign {
  float: left;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Sign {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProgressWrap">
  <div class="Overlay">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ProgressPercent">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Setting `color` as value

```js
var value = 0,
  pos = 0,
  progressHidden = false,
  progressEl = $('.ProgressPercent'),
  timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

var ProgressColourTween = [
  "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
  "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
  "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
  "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
  "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
  "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
  "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
  "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
  "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
  "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
];

function progress() {

  // run counter
  value++;
  if (value <= 100) {
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').text(value);
    $('.Overlay .Percent').text(value);
    $('.ProgressPercent .Percent').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressPercent .Sign').css({
      "color": ProgressColourTween[value]
    });
    $('.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent').css({
      background: "-webkit-linear-gradient(#CCCCCC, #CCCCCC 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%)"
    });
  }
  
}
```

```css
.ProgressWrap {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay {
  position: absolute;
}
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .Overlay .Sign {
  float: left;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#CCC, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Percent,
.ProgressWrap .ProgressPercent .Sign {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ProgressWrap">
  <div class="Overlay">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ProgressPercent">
    <div class="Percent">0</div>
    <div class="Sign">%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first code sample works perfectly for my question **1). Overlaid Text Does Not Appear To Be Same Size**, thank you for this. Do you have any solution for my 2nd question please?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this is a fix as the colour changes with the other colour changing and it needs to be one solid colour throughout. I just noticed the way you couldn't see the other colour behind, however upon trying to work with this, I don't understand why setting the colour to white makes it yellow and whatnot. What is the second example trying to show in your answer?

Comment: @TimMarshall The second stacksnippet attempts to use `mix-blend-mode` set to `color` to display top of `%` character as `#ccc`.